# Why render error occurred in reactnative?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

> Render Error
>
> View config getter callback for component `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FPDFier-40b67400-36c7-4020-b3c5-8b11d20ec8bf/ImagePicker/ca4dcc5d-bd51-43c2-99a6-a5ea1681652a.png` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

**Here is the code**

```
import { Image, Button, ScrollView, Pressable, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { Stack } from "expo-router";

import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker';

const CreatePDF = () => {

  const [hasGalleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);

  const [Image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const [docPath, setdocPath] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {

      const galleryStatus = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

      setGalleryPermission(galleryStatus.status === 'granted');

    })();

  }, []);

  const pickDocument = async () => {

    let resultdoc = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({

      multiple: true,

      base64: true,

    });

    if (!resultdoc.canceled) {

      console.log(resultdoc);

    }

  };

  const pickImage = async () => {

    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({

      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,

      quality: 1,

      allowsMultipleSelection: true,

    });

    if (!result.canceled) {

      console.log(result);

      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);

    }

  };

  if (hasGalleryPermission === false) {

    return <Text> no access to gallery</Text>;

  }

  return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>

      <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} />

      <View style={styles.recentlyCreated}>

        <Text style={styles.recentText}> Recently created </Text>

      </View>

      <View style={styles.recentContainerTop}>

        <View style={styles.recentContainer} />

      </View>

      <View>

        <Pressable onPress={pickDocument}>

          <Text> hello </Text>

        </Pressable>

        <Pressable onPress={pickImage}>

          <Text> hello </Text>

        </Pressable>

        <Text>{Image}</Text>

        {Image && <Image source={{ uri: Image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}

      </View>

    </View>

  );

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  recentlyCreated: {

    marginTop: 20,

    marginLeft: 10,

  },

  recentText: {

    fontSize: 18,

    fontWeight: 'bold',

  },

  recentContainerTop: {

    marginTop: 20,

    marginLeft: 10,

    marginRight: 10,

  },

  recentContainer: {

    height: 200,

    width: '100%',

    backgroundColor: '#eee',

  },

});

export default CreatePDF;
```

Sometime this error shows

> State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

Expected behaviour: It show render image on screen after i chose it from expo image picker.

how to store multiple assets uri in setImage and display on screen in a scrollView?